# How do I do Woocommerce address update with hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to update the address with the following hook, but it doesn't work. is there anyone who can help?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_save_address_validation', 'custom_validation', 10, 3 ); 
function custom_validation($user_id,$load_address)
{
    if( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the change shipping address in Woocommerce use this hook

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

$fields['shipping']['custom_field'] = array(
    'label' => 'Custom field',
    'required' => 1,
    'class' => array ('address-field', 'update_totals_on_change' )
);

return $fields;
```

}
For the change billing address in Woocommerce use this hook

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3);

function custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text)
{
    $_billing_my_field = get_post_meta($order->id, '_billing_my_field', true);
    if ($plain_text)
    {
        echo 'My field is ' . $_billing_my_field;
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<p>My field is  ' . $_billing_my_field . '</p>';
    }
}
```